# Objects exceeding body width

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a fixed *header* and a table stretching to 100% of the page, simple right?
For some reason, the table is stretching over 100% of the body. I have a example of the code below. I have a example website but you have to sign up and register for it. If you'd still like the link I will provide it.

```
<body style="max-width: 100%">
<div style="top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; position: fixed">Example Header</div>
<table style="width: 100%">
     <tr>
         <td>
            Example table.
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing any margins and paddings in your table and divs?

Comment: @IvanIvković yes I have. I also looked at all the widths set to any objects within the body to see if they would exceed the body but they don't.

Comment: Can I pls see the code or the webpage? Does it have any non-inline CSS?

Comment: @IvanIvković see my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The table's parent is the body so it makes sense for it to take the width from the body...

Comment: Exactly the problem. For some reason, the table is extending over the body's width.

Comment: Ah I see now. Wording was a little confusing at this late hour. :P Can you post a jsFiddle replicating the problem or link to the site itself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the mechanics behind this, but the cells in a table stretch out to fill it's width if their content fits in it, but if it doesn't, they start to stretch the table too.
Unfortunately, there are restrictions on defining width to table-cells also.